# Data structure - Array

Tags: arrays, data-structures

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) it says:

> Arrays are useful mostly because the element indices can be computed
>   at run time. Among other things, this feature allows a single
>   iterative statement to process arbitrarily many elements of an array.
>   For that reason, the elements of an array data structure are required
>   to have the same size and should use the same data representation.

Is this still true for modern languages?

For example, Java, you can have an array of Objects or Strings, right? Each object or string can have different length. Do I misunderstand the above quote, or languages like Java implements Array differently? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java all types except primitives are referenced types meaning they are a pointer to some memory location manipulated by `JVM`.

But there are mainly two types of programming languages, `fixed-typed` like `Java` and `C++` **and** `dynamically-typed` like `python` and `PHP`. In `fixed-typed` languages your array should consist of the same types whether `String`, `Object` or ...
but in `dynamically-typed` ones there's a bit more abstraction and you can have different data types in array (I don't know the actual implementation though).

Comment: @RyanVincent, thanks for that, updated the answer. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

An array is a regular arrangement of data in memory. Think of an array of soldiers, all in a line, with exactly equal spacing between each man.

So they can be indexed by lookup from a base address. But all items have to be the same size. So if they are not, you store pointers or references to make them the same size. All languages use that underlying structure, except for what are sometimes called "associative arrays", indexed by key (strings usually), where you have what is called a hash table. Essentially the hash function converts the key into an array index, with a fix-up to resolve collisions.